# Merge [injection] into [code-injection]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

I’d like to propose a merge of the tag [injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/injection) to [code-injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-injection) as the latter is the [proper term](https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/94.html).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dependencies+injection

Comment: @RobertHarvey I guess you probably clear on this, but what you link is a different suggestion. You point out the `[dependencies]` and `[injection]` tags to be merged into the `[dependency-injection]` tag for [that pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). But this question is about the thing associated most commonly with [sql injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) which currently also has two tags, `[injection]` and `[code-injection]`.